# Search SharePoint 2007

Tags: search-results

Can I create a search box to only search specific data entered into a custom form?  I want to be able to create search box and when criteria is entered I want it to return the matching data below the search box.  I thought maybe the web part Filter Text would work by using the connection to connect it to a list form, but couldn't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some jQuery to "search on this page" when viewing the form.  The guys over at EndUserSharePoint.com have a good blog post on accomplishing just that: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/search-on-this-page-using-jquery.aspx